# I loaded iOS7.0.2 on my iPhone and all of the purchased apps I had have disappeared from the screen

Tags: ios

I finally downloaded iOS7.0.2 on my iPhone 4s (I didn't want to do it because I expected something to go wrong).  It worked fine on my ipad which is a much newer version but on the phone all of my purchased apps have disappeared from the screen. If you go to the app store I can open them I just can't get them to reappear - how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`Settings > General > Reset > Reset Home Screen Layout` Should sort you out.